# Embeding grafana iframe in Angular with authentication - token in header

Tags: angular, iframe, header, token, grafana

I'm trying to embed grafana iframe into Angular application. Now I have grafana behind proxy server and in proxy server I'm adding credentials for viever into request headers.

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe!: ElementRef;

public setGrafanaIframe() {
  let randomSeed = "&random=" + (new Date()).getTime() + new Date(); //Random number added to URL params to prevent browser from caching iframe content
  this.iframe.nativeElement.src = this._someService.getGrafanaUrl).toString() + randomSeed
}
```

I've also tried to get blob:

HTML:

```
<iframe #iframe class="responsive-iframe"></iframe>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe!: ElementRef;

public setGrafanaIframe() {
  let randomSeed = "&random=" + (new Date()).getTime() + new Date(); //Random number added to URL params to prevent browser from caching iframe content
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('TOKEN...');
  let url = this._someService.getGrafanaUrl().toString() + randomSeed
  this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob', headers: headers}).subscribe((response) => {
    this.iframe.nativeElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(response)
})
```

}

But the result was that:
[Grafana iframe with blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luqzn.png)

I know that it's because browser haven't downloaded CSS files - and thats true, in *Network* page in ChromeDevTools there is no additional requests for CSS files.

Is somebody knows how to embed grafana iframe into Angular application with auth token in headers?